# PG Error trying to push rails db to heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to push my rails db to heroku using: heroku run rake db:migrate and getting the following error:

```
=  ChangeDateFormatInMyTable: migrating ======================================
-- change_column(:users, :date_of_birth, :datetime)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  column "date_of_birth" cannot be cast to type "pg_catalog.timestamp"
: ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "date_of_birth" TYPE timestamp
```

Comment: What is the current type of :date_of_birth? You may need to explicitly convert the current values in that column to the new type.

Comment: :datetime... even when i do a db reset before trying to push to heroku i get this error...@kwbeam

Comment: What is the contents of that specific migration?

Comment: Yeah, why are you issuing a `change_column` if it’s already a `datetime`? Showing the migration code for everything involving `:date_of_birth` would help.

Comment: Well i did several migrations changing the datatype in attempts to fix this problem (also changed the name from date_of_birth to dob).. the last being "change_column :users, :dob, :datetime"

Comment: even when i delete the migration causing the issue in the console (ChangeDateFormatInMyTable) i get the same error..

Comment: You aren’t giving enough information for us to help you. If there are several migrations, we need to see all of them relating to this field.

Comment: It's not clear what the current column type is (*before* the failing migration) and what you are migrating it to. In your question, could you update it to include (1) what the current rails and database type of that column is, and (2) what type you are converting it to.

Comment: The current is datetime... i am not trying to convert it to anything, i removed that migration.. just need to push to heroku

Comment: the only relevant one left is the original.. class AddBirthdayToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :date_of_birth, :string
  end
end

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL there is not a data type called `datetime`, unless you added it. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/datatype-datetime.html From the error it is clear that the statement is trying to convert an existing column to type `timestamp without time zone` (which, incidentally, doesn't sound like the ideal data type for a date of birth column), from a type which doesn't have an implicit cast to that type, like maybe some character string type. At the SQL level, that would need a USING clause, so you could specify the conversion.

Comment: Thanks.. a little confused from your answer as to what i should convert the birthday column to in my rails app..

Answer (score 2):

Try a heroku run rake db:reset

Often times with Heroku and my PG Database, I have to do resets when I have massively changed things.

Answer (score 1):

Yes "Heroku run rake db:reset" definitely works. I have been having a similar problem

```
RemoveGirthFromProfile: migrating =========================================
-- remove_column(:profiles, :girth)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  column "girth" of relation "profiles" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "profiles" DROP "girth"
```

but when i reseted the database it solve the application errors i was even having on heroku